# jQuery Plugin - access a child value from outside within the different parent variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am new to jQuery and especially to JavaScript.

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin but have some difficulties with callback events. I want to include callback events into different functions, so that the plugin will be a little bit flexible.

Here is the code:

```
    (function($, undefined){

    var methods = {

        init: function(options){

            var settings = $.extend({

                // Default settings
                'fadeInOutSpeed'            : 100,
                // the rest of default settings ...

                // Callback events
                onOpenBefore        : function(){},
                onOpen              : function(){},
                onOpenedCloseBefore : function(){}
                // the rest of the callback events...

            }, options);

            // code goes here...

            return this.each(function(){

                // code goes here

            });

        },
        destroy: function(){
            // code goes here
        },
        open: function(){
            console.info('method open accessed');
        },
        close: function(){
            console.info('method close accessed');
        },
        update: function(){
            console.info('method update accessed');
        }

    };

    function gui_selectbox_open(param, event){

        // HOW TO PUT A CORRECT CALLBACK CODE HERE ?
        settings.onOpenBefore.call(param, event);

        // function code goes here

        settings.onOpenAfter.call(param, event);
    };
```

Inside the function `gui_selectbox_open(param,event)`, there is a line at the beginning, where I want to put a callback event, so I could access it properly when initializing a plugin from outside, which gives me an JavaScript error, telling that `settings.onOpenBefore...` is not defined. How to define it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `settings` is defined as local to the `init()` function inside your `methods` object. to make it accessible outside, you can define it outside the `init` function and access it as `methods.settings.yourMethod(..)`

i.e.

```
var methods = {

    settings: null,

    init: function(options){

    ...
```

Comment: I'am sorry for being dumb, I just can't get it, I've tried `methods.init(settings.onOpenBefore.call(param, event));` and `methods.init(onOpenBefore.call(param, event));` and `methods.settings(init.onOpenBefore.call(param, event));` but none of them works. Can you please describe a little bit more ? Thank you

Comment: You should be able to call them as `methods.settings.onOpenBefore(...);`

Comment: here is how i dealed with them: i've created a `var settings: null` before `var methods = {...`, so it would be a global variable, and then inside `var methods = { init:function(options){....`
Thanks @techfoobar, for pointing me at the right direction.